# Axios can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm trying to use Axios in node like I would use something like CURL. I am making an api request to my node endpoint. I then use Axios to make a request to Spotify to do some OAuth stuff. I get the response back from the Axios request successfully but when I try and return a response in Express I am told the headers have already been sent. Below is a test I have set up to isolate the issue. This give the error "Can't set headers after they are sent".

```
makeRequest: function(req, res, next) {

    axios.get('https://google.com')
        .then(function(){
            res.status(200).send({});
        });
}
```

Can this be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think because I was modifying the headers of every request it was causing some problems, e.g.

```
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH');
```

I used a different router for the requests that I use Axios and it works OK now. Something like:

```
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
app.use('/callback', axiosRouter);

apiRouter.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH');
}

//I don't modify the axiosRouter headers
```

Comment: I'm not sure what were you talking about, but you're not suppose to set header after you've sent response.